# How can I write to firestore within a firestore triggered function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I set up the following function in firebase and it is triggering, if I add a new document into the collection `userAdd`.
And it all works as long as I don't try to write somewhere else into firestore. Here with by using the variable `firestoreDB`. As soon as I am doing this nothing works anymore. Not even my logs are written anymore. What am I missing here?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const firestoreDB = admin.firestore();

exports.adduser = functions.
  region('europe-west1')
  .firestore
  .document('userAdd/{useradd}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newValue = snap.data();
    admin.auth().createUser({
      email: newValue.contact_email,
      emailVerified: false,
      password: 'topsecret',
      displayName: newValue.contact_email,
      disabled: false
    })
    .then(function(userRecord) {
      const userData = {
        "_id": userRecord.uid,
        "displayName": newValue.contact_email
      };
      console.log(userData);
      return firestoreDB.collection('users').add(userData);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not dealing with promises correctly.  Your function [must return a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) that resolves with all the asynchronous work is complete.  Right now, you are ignoring the promise chain returned by `admin.auth().createUser()...`.  You should return that promise chain from the function so Cloud Functions knows when it's safe to clean up.  Otherwise, the work might never complete.

```
return admin.auth().createUser(...)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```